# Get PostId for custom post types

Tags: wordpress

I want to find the PostId for customPost type and update the publish post to draft mode, for custom post type its giving blank array or PostId as 0.

I am doing this update part inside foreach loop.

```
foreach ($file_data as $link){
  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost'){
      $postId = url_to_postid("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
.$link); 
    }else{
        $postId = url_to_postid($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$link); 
    }
    if(isset($postId) && (!is_null(get_post($postId) &&  
is_numeric($postId)))) {
        $status = get_post_status( $postId );
        if($status == 'publish'){
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID'    =>  $postId,
                'post_status'   =>  'draft'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more information about your requirements?

Comment: a post type (CPT) itsself does to my knowledge not have a Post ID. Post IDs are for posts only. (with posts i mean any CPT post)
What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Frizzant, I want to have function like default wordpress function (url_to_postid) it gives postId through permalink but for default post not for custom post type posts.
So I want to find postId for custom Post types post.

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani, I want to have function like default wordpress function (url_to_postid) it gives postId through permalink but for default post not for custom post type posts.
So I want to find postId for custom Post types post.

Comment: the default post is technically a custom post type too. It's just called "post". Works exactly the same as the others, but has some presets.

Can I ask why you want to to URL to post_ID? It is always the last thing to resort to, since it is the least reliable way to get the post ID.

Comment: @Frizzant, I have updated my question you can check my requirement there

Comment: so does the updating work, or not?

Comment: PostID I get for only default postType not for custom Post Type, so the update works for default only, not for CPT

Comment: this might help:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/#user-contributed-notes